# socket.io emit doesn't work in qupzilla

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I've wrote a simple app and tested in Chrome. All works fine!
Now I'm testing with qupzilla, but when I trigger the .emit function, nothing happens!
From chrome i wrote a thing, the object is updated and sent to server, server does a broadcast. All fine (qupzilla receives the update too).
But, if I write something on qupzilla, this update isn't sent to server (No logs in node)

Here's some code.

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
io.set("log level", 1);
var dataStored = [];
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('event', dataStored);
    socket.on('update', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        dataStored = data;
        socket.broadcast.emit("event", data);
    });
});
```

And client side:

```
$scope.things = [];
$scope.pushingObj = "";
// socket
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080", {
    'connect timeout': 500,
    reconnect: true,
    'reconnection delay': 500,
    'reopen delay': 500,
    'max reconnection attempts': 10000
});
socket.on("event", function(data) {
    $scope.things = data;
    $scope.$apply();
});
//
$scope.pushObj = function() {
    //console.log($scope.pushingObj);
    $scope.things.push($scope.pushingObj);
    socket.emit("update", $scope.things);
    $scope.pushingObj = "";
}
```

Comment: what do  you get on your client console?

Comment: nothing. No errors, no network activity. Nothing. After a emit is sent the receive data doesn't work anymore.. I saw that my app receives datas only at first page access. Any ideas? :)